# In pytorch, how to calculate gradient for a element in a tensor when it is used to calculate another element in this tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient

In this pytorch code:

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor([2.], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.zeros((10))
gt = torch.zeros((10))

y[0] = a
y[1] = y[0] * 2
y.retain_grad()

loss = torch.sum((y-gt) ** 2)
loss.backward()
print(y.grad)
```

I want y[0]'s gradient to consist 2 parts:

1. loss backward to y[0] itself.
2. y[0] is used to calculate y[1], so it should have the part of y[1]'s gradient.

but when I run this code, there is only part 1 in y[0]'s gradient.

So how to make y[0]'s gradient to have all 2 parts?

edit: the output is:

```
tensor([4., 8., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

but I expect:

```
tensor([20., 8., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Comment: I am a beginner - 
Hi @Shai @Decarbonized formaldehyde - how is the `a.grad = (y[0] - 0) ^ + (y[1] - 0)^2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y[0]` and `y[1]` are two different elements, therefore they have different `grad`. The only thing that "binds" them is the underlying relation to `a`. If you inspect the grad of `a`, you'll see:

```py
print(a.grad)
```

> ```
> tensor([20.])
> ```

That is, the two parts of the gradients are combined in `a.grad`.